# Why rails does not render my custom layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ProductsController in between ApplicationController and all my other controllers(MiddleLayerController < ApplicationController and others < MiddleLayerController). And I have a custom layout(products.html.erb) for checking logging status so I don't repeat this kind of code in almost every view file:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  render some html
<% else %>
  <% redirect_to_root %>
<% end %>
```

When I tried to access a page using /pages(PagesController < ProductsController) when I'm logged out, it still renders the html without checking the login state in products layout.
Here's what's in products layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Products</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <% if logged_in? %>
      <%= yield %>
    <% else %>
      <% redirect_to_root %>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm wondering why this happens.

Comment: What's the purpose of redirect_to_root? The layout renders with nothing on it I assume.  The correct way to redirect is inside the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put redirection code in a layout/view, I think it won't work and even if it did it's the job of the controller, not the view.

I would use a before_action in your parent controller (can potentially also go in ApplicationController itself).

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_login

    private
       def require_login
          redirect_to(root_path) unless logged_in?
       end
 end
```